# Azure port-forwarding issue

Tags: azure, iis, firewall

I have a virtual machine on azure. On the VM with Windows Server 2012 I have a web-site which is published via IIS7. I wrote bindings for the web-site, changed a port to 8080 and now able to access it with it's ip: 10.0.0.4:8080. Now I want to have an access to this web-site via internet. My VM has static ip, for instance 1.2.3.4. I added a rule on my virtual machine for 8080 for windows firewall, to allow all connections for this port. I suppose now I need to edit binding on the azure manager, I read a lot of articles (e.g. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/) but I don't have 'Endpoints' menu. The only one I have is: inbound rules and outbound rules, so I've tried to do port-forwarding there (screenshot: http://take.ms/MgLWq). But it doesn't work, I still don't have access from the outside.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your link is about endpoints which is only available in the old portal (https://manage.windowsazure.com). From your screenshot I see that you use the new portal (https://portal.azure.com).

What you have to do is the following:
1. In the new portal go to your VM and click on "All settings"
2. Select "Network interfaces" and select the network interface with the public IP address. (Probably there is only one.)
3. Select the "Network security group" and click on "All settings"
4. Select "Inbound security rules"
5. Click "Add" and create a new inbound rule with the following settings:

- Name: any name, e.g. "Web"
- Priority: any number lower 65500
- Source: any or Internet
- Protocol: any or TCP
- Source port range: * **(important difference to your configuration)**
- Destination: Any
- Destination port range: 8080 (IIS' configured port)
- Action: Allow

Save it, wait a minute, and that's it.

**And here are some screenshots for clarification**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you,
The origin of issue was source port range.